# Port not exposed but still reachable on internal docker network

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

(I'm having the inverse problem of exposing a port and it's not reachable.)

In my case I have 2 containers on the same network. One is an Alpine Python running a Python Flask app. The other is a barebones Ubuntu 18.04. The services are initialised basically like this:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  pythonflask:
    build: someDockerfile # from python:3.6-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped

  ubuntucontainer:
    build: someOtherDockerfile #from ubuntu:18.04
    depends_on:
      - pythonflask
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The Python Flask app runs on port 5000.
Notice the lack of `expose: - 5000` in the **docker-compose.yml** file.
The problem is that I'm able to get a correct response when cURLing http://pythonflask:5000 from inside `ubuntucontainer`

Steps:

```
$ docker exec -it ubuntucontainer /bin/bash
```

...and then within the container...

```
root@ubuntucontainer:/# curl http://pythonflask:5000/
```

...correctly returns my response from the Flask app.

However from my machine running docker:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/
```

Doesn't return anything (as expected).

As I test different ports, they get automatically exposed each time. What is doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connectivity between containers is achieved by placing the containers on the same docker network and communicating over the container ip and port (rather than the host published port). So what does expose do then?

### Expose is documentation

Expose in docker is used by image creators to document the expected port that the application will listen on inside the container. With the exception of some tools and a flag in docker that uses this metadata documentation, it is not used to control access between containers or modify docker's networking. Applications may be reconfigured at runtime to listen to a different port, and you can connect to ports that have not been exposed.

For DNS lookups between containers, the network needs to be user created, not one of the default networks from docker (e.g. DNS is not enabled in the default bridge network named "bridge"). With DNS, you can lookup the container name, service name (from a compose file), and any network aliases created for that container on that network.

The other half of the equation is "publish" in docker. This creates a mapping from the host to the container to allow external access. It is implemented with a proxy process that runs on the host and forwards new connections. Because of the implementation, you can publish a port on the host even if the container is not listening on the port, though you would receive an error when trying to connect to that port in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of `expose: ...` just means that there is no port exposed from the service group you defined in your docker-compose.yml

Within the images you use, there are still exposed ports which are reachable from within the network that is automatically created by docker-compose.

That is why you reach one container from within another. In addition every container can be accessed via service name from the docker-compose.yml on the internal network.

You should not be able to access flask from your host (`http://localhost:5000`)